# Hide PHP Variables in URL with url rewrite

Tags: php, variables, url-rewriting, get

I am working on a site that has to deal with reservation numbers and I need to pass variables to confirmation page. Currently when you arrive at `confirmation.php` the URL looks something like the below:

```
http://localhost/confirmation.php?reservation_id=1&proceed=no
```

These variables are sent via a link to this page from the index page.  I need a way to either encrypt the `$reservation_id` OR rewrite my URL so it looks like this

```
http://localhost/confirmation.php
```

...but still have access to my variables. I have tried sessions and some encryption methods, but cant find anything that wont over complicate the page as I am trying to keep it as simple as possible. Forms with hidden fields is not an option, I am printing all the reservations in links with a loop from the database.

Thanks!

Comment: You want do something complicated, but you don't want to over-complicated the page?

Comment: Why do you need to encrypt these things?

Comment: Put them in a session. The values are only available server-side. The only thing that is sent to the browser is a reference to session.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use session variables. Create a random session variable name, and assign the reservation information to it:

```
foreach ($reservations as $r) {
    $random = make_random_string(); // You need to write this function
    $_SESSION[$random] = $r;
    echo "<a href='reservation.php?id=$random'>...</a>";
}
```

Then `reservation.php` can look up `$_SESSION[$_GET['id']]` to get the reservation information.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to start a session and pass the data in there. Or, you could POST the data instead (Use a form). But the session is probably the better choice.

Comment: He said forms are not an option, it sounds like it's a table of links. Like on Expedia when it lists all your itineraries.

Comment: @Barmar I don't know if that was there and I didn't see it or if it was added in an edit. Either way, Sounds like sessions are the right choice.